# How to show that $v$ is the classical derivative of $u$ without using FTC?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $v \in L^¹(a,b)$ and define the function $$u(x):=\int_{x_0}^xv(\xi)\ d\xi, \  \ x \in [a,b], x_0 \in [a,b]$$

How can I show that $v$ is the generalized derivative of $u$ on $[a,b]$ without making use of the fundamental theorem of calculus on $u$? I appreciate any hint.

Comment: You need stronger assumptions on $v$ than $v\in L^1$. Consider $v(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational, and $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I can't see myself what problem occurs. If we chose $v$ as mentioned, integrating it gives us $x-x_0$ if $x$ is irrational and $=0$ otherwise. Or what am I supposed to do with $v$?

Comment: No. Study  up a little on the Lebesgue integral: If $v(x)=1$ for irrational $x$, 0 for rational $x$ then $u(x)=x-x_0$ for _every_ $x$. So $u'(x)=1$ fr every $x$, so $u'=v$ _almost everywhere_.

Comment: Thank you, got it - forgot about the exact definition of the Lebesgue integral. Also, I actually made a mistake when posting this question:

I meant "generalized derivative" instead of "classical derivative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not in general true. By integration by parts, you can show that $v$ is a weak derivative of $u$. If $u$ has a classical derivative, then $v$ must be that derivative. However, there's no guarantee that $u$ here has a classical derivative.

---

Integration by parts: $$ \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = \left(\int^x f(x) g(\xi)d\xi\right)\biggr\rvert_a^b - \int_a^b\int^x f'(x) g(\xi)d\xi dx $$

Let $f\in C^\infty([a,b])$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and let $g(x) = v(x)$, and you will recover the definition of weak derivative.

Comment: Thank you. How can I integrate it by parts in this case to show that $v$ is a weak derivative of $u$?

Comment: I've added the integration by parts as an edit.